# Ordering by number of one-to-many entries

Tags: django, django-models

I have models like this:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Entry(models.Model):
    entry = models.TextField()
    good = models.BooleanField()
    f = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
```

I want to list all Forum objects ordered by [the number of Entry objects in that forum satisfying good == True]. How can I do this with Django model methods?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Sum
result = Forum.objects.filter(entry__good=True).annotate(Sum('entry')).order_by('-entry__sum')
```

-entry__sum - it's order from big to small count of good entry, if need order from small to big, then order_by('entry__sum')